# cmake, построить дерево проекта Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cmake

Необходимо при помощи `CMake` построить проект в Visual Studio  с сохранением древовидной структуры.
Структура имеет следующий вид

```
Main (dir)
  +-- CMakeLists.txt
  +-- main.cpp
  +-- Logging(dir)
      +-- CMakeLists.txt
      +-- MyLog.cpp
      +-- MyLog.h
  +-- InputOutput(dir)
      +-- CMakeLists.txt
      +-- InputOutput.cpp
      +-- InputOutput.h
```

Долгие поиски  привели меня вот к такому варианту

**Main/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.10)
project(Main CXX)
set(
    source_list
    "main.cpp"
    "Logging/MyLog.cpp"
    "Logging/MyLog.h"
     "InputOutput/InputOutput.cpp"
     "InputOutput/InputOutput.h"
   )

add_executable(Main ${source_list})

foreach(source IN LISTS source_list)
  get_filename_component(source_path "${source}" PATH)
  string(REPLACE "/" "\\" source_path_msvc "${source_path}")
  source_group("${source_path_msvc}" FILES "${source}")
endforeach()
```

**Main/Logging/CmakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

FILE(GLOB LOCAL_SOURCE   
    "*.h"
    "*.cpp"
   )
SET(SOURCE
   ${SOURCE}
   ${LOCAL_SOURCE}
   PARENT_SCOPE
 )

SOURCE_GROUP(Logging FILES ${LOCAL_SOURCE})
```

**Main/InputOutput/CmakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

FILE(GLOB LOCAL_SOURCE   
    "*.h"
    "*.cpp"
   )
SET(SOURCE
   ${SOURCE}
   ${LOCAL_SOURCE}
   PARENT_SCOPE
 )

SOURCE_GROUP(InputOutputFILES ${LOCAL_SOURCE})
```

Древовидная структура действительно отображается в  visual studio, однако сами файлы и папки не копируются в дирректорию `build`. И не корректными оказываются инклуды вида: `#include "Logging\MyLog.h"` в файле **"InputOutput/InputOutput.h"**. Подскажите как исправить это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение: подключить в основной `CmakeLists` вот такую директорию `include_directories( ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})`. Теперь во всех папках в главной директории видны файлы из других папок

Answer (score 2):

Может достаточно использовать [`use_folders`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_gbl/USE_FOLDERS.html) ?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.10)
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)

project(Main CXX)
```

Comment: ситуация никак не изменилась - иcходники по прежнему не скопировались в папку build  и  инклуды не работают
п.с. кеш очистил

Comment: Хотел просто, что бы в папке build  создавались так же копии всех исходников, но это не важно, да и не нужно мне. 
Основная проблема в том, как сделать, что бы в файлах в папке "InputOutput/" были видны файлы из папки "Logging/" и наоборот соответственно.  Допустим в файле   Main/main.cpp  никаких проблем нет и все файлы из других папок подключаются через инклуды

Comment: @ Abyx , методом тыка нашел решение :  подключить в основной CmakeLists вот такую директорию include_directories( ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}). Теперь во всех папках в главной директории видны файлы из других папок